# I put my InkWell widget on a row but it is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I put my Inkwell widget inside a row and made each widget expanded. This is to make both take exactly half of the screen vertically.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(    
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(    
        body: Container(
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Column( 
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(     
                    children: <Widget>[ 
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container (
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp2()),
                              );
                            },
                          )
                        )
                      ),
                      Expanded (
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.grey
                        )
                      ),         
                    ],
                  )
                )
              ],
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }

}
```

But for some reason the InkWell white widget is not opening the page 'MyApp2'. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split your `MaterialApp` widget to another class as shown.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'MyApp2.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            child: SafeArea(
                child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: Container(child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp2()),
                );
              },
            ))),
            Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.grey)),
          ],
        ))
      ],
    ))));
  }
}
```

The reason is you are using a `context` that is a parent of `MaterialApp`, the context is passed to `build` of `MyApp`. As a result, `MyApp`'s `BuildContext` doesn't have a `MaterialApp` as parent.
In your case, as `MyApp` needs a `MaterialApp` as parent for navigation in the class to work, you can extract `Scaffold` to another class and left `MaterialApp` in `MyApp`.